# Row transpose with value from a second column in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pySpark dataframe with 4 columns (C1, C2, C3 and C4). In third column (C3) I have categorical values such as V1, V2, V3 and in fourth column (C4) I have its corresponding numeric values. I am trying to add additional columns V1, V2 and V3 where value of these new columns shall come from corresponding rows of 4th column (C4)

I am able to transpose row to columns through `UDF` and `DF.withColumn` but unable to bring the values

```
def valTocat(C3):
if C3 == 'xyz':
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

but the following is not working

```
def valTocat((C3, C4)):
if C3 == 'xyz':
    return C4
else:
    return 0
```

Somehow I am unable to post the tabular format of the data but I think it is easy to visualize.

Some suggestion will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `pivot()` your `DataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.groupBy("c1","c2") \
 .pivot("c3") \
 .agg(expr("coalesce(first(c4))")).show()
```

You need the function `coalesce` to substitute the missing values with a `null`.